# extraneous arguments

Tags: linux

When I type in console

```
dnssec-keygen -a HMAC-MD5 -b 128 -n USER DHCP_UPDATER Kdhcp-updater.+157+46827
```

I've got `fatal:extraneous arguments`

It's Ubuntu 11.04 server.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://ftp.isc.org/www/bind/arm95/man.dnssec-keygen.html), `dnssec-keygen` only takes a single non-option argument (the key name).  You're passing it three (`DHCP_UPDATER Kdhcp-updater.+157+46827`).  The full synopsis is:

```
dnssec-keygen {-a algorithm} {-b keysize} {-n nametype} [-c class] [-e] 
  [-f flag] [-g generator] [-h] [-k] [-p protocol] [-r randomdev] 
  [-s strength] [-t type] [-v level] {name}
```

The man page has some examples of correct usage.